# Search and replace "@" values within XML tags using regex

Tags: java, regex, xml

I am trying to build a regex where i am trying to do a generic search and replace of all the "@" that occur within the xml tags <> and replace it with "_"

BEFORE:-

```
  <@name>DISCOUNT@MARKETPLACE</@name>
    <@call>313@4445169</@call>
    <address@>31st avenue</@address>
```

AFTER:-

```
 <name>DISCOUNT@MARKETPLACE</name>
    <call>313@4445169</call>
    <address>31st avenue</address>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't match description. Instead of replacing @ with _ you removed it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend.

Comment: You mention changing `"@"` to `"_"`, but your example changes it to a blank `""`. Do you want `<@foo>bar</@foo>` to become `<_foo>bar</_foo>` or do you really want `<foo>bar</foo>`?

Answer (score -1):

Capture the all-but-the-leading-@ of a tag name that starts with `@` in group 1, its attributes+content in group 2, and match the tag end using a backreference, and reconstruct without the `@`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<@([^ >]+)(.*?</)@\\1>", "<$1$2$1>");
```

An important point is the use of a *reluctant* quantifier `*?`, which matches as *little* as possible, so a match isn't made that spans across two like-named tags capturing them both and everything in between.

This code has been tested and passes using the sample in the question. I also tested it with XML attributes, which also work, ie

```
<@name foo="@bar">DISCOUNT@MARKETPLACE</@name>
```

is converted to:

```
<name foo="@bar">DISCOUNT@MARKETPLACE</name>
```